# Linearly Scale Light Temperature

Tags: drivers, lighting

I want to have a plane which goes from temperature x to temperature y with respect to one of its sides. I was looking into drivers but this doesn't seem to accommodate geometry, only scale and position. Is there anyway that I can linearly increase the emission temperature of a plane surface with respect to the length of one of its sides; say its width.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map color temperature like you can map any other shader value with nodes, no need to involve drivers unless required.

[image]

Just use either direct texture coordinates as input for a *Color Mix* node, or use *World Coordinates* from a *Geometry* node instead.

Separate the desired direction, use math nodes to adjust length of progression, then feed it into a *Color Mix* with each temperature plugged to a *Color* socket.

[image]

Alternatively for more complex progression patterns you may use a gradient texture.

Comment: Nice answer, are you sure that the color is correctly interpolated with the mix. Wouldn't [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiOiE.png) be more accurate?

Comment: Yup, there's a [difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H6i6.png), unless I messed up the math.

Comment: You're probably right. My mistake, I didn't give much though to the progression part, since you can basically changing it easily to suit your needs using either gradient textures, UVs or different mixing modes

Comment: thanks so much I had no idea there was a geometry node!!!