# Gradient lighting

Tags: lighting

[image]

Hi There, I got a lighting question for you all; I come from a photography background and for product photography, using gradient lighting is very common for lighting reflective objects. So a gradient of light, from bright to less bright. Attached is an image as an example. I tried different methods but can't seem to get the same look in Blender as in real life. Is there anyone who could help me with it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello :). Just to save time - what methods have you tried so far?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51172/gradient-glowing-object-how-to/51176#51176 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137899/linearly-scale-light-temperature/138929#138929 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66853/northern-lights-effect-along-line-on-textured-plane/66870#66870

Comment: @JachymMichal, As the comment of Duarte suggests this is something that needs to be done in nodes. I tried to do it physically the way we do it in real life. For example having a 'scrim', so a half transparent material plane, which I then shine a light trough at an angle, that didn't work. I also tried a white plane and bouncing the light of of that at an angle, that also did't work. Using nodes seem to be a good option, but I would love it if there was a more 'physical' option so I could just adjust it in the viewport, that would be way easier to understand and adjust for me. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using translucent objects to difuse the light through, Illuminate planes (or even better, a hemisphere that surrounds the scene) using spot lights. Use a large size in the spot shape and use a large value for blend, that should give you the gradient you are looking for, As you know already, lighting shiny and reflective objects is all about lighting whatever is

Comment: Thanks @susu, I'll definitely try that!